# Is it possible to get a .NET List<T> to show up in VBA?

Tags: .net, vba, list

**Nutshell:**

Is it possible to get VBA to interface with lists created in a .NET (C#) class library? I see that `List<T>` belongs to `System.Collections.Generic` so can I not easily get VBA use this somehow?

**Background:**

I have a C#-built interface for a class which creates IntelliSense options in VBA:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("47BC2BB4-B7AA-427E-9971-4EA996412D709813")]
public interface IMyClass
{
    bool Test1 { get; set; }
    List<NameSpacer.CustomClass> MyListOfCustoms { get; }
}
```

And `MyClass` is derived from the interface, I have everything set up correctly with the progID and blahblah so basically all my fields and properties show up fine when using this class in VBA in Access or Excel...

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("JamHeadArt.MyClass")]
[Guid("60437B5C-5AFE-491C-9264-7475A96AE321")]
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public bool Test1 { get; set; }
    public List <NameSpacer.CustomClass> MyListOfCustoms { get; private set; }
}
```

Except for the List! I'm wondering is it possible to get VBA to see a List? Since VBA doesn't deal with lists...

It's not my NameSpacer, since the CustomClass belongs to a sub-namespace - I tried changing to global namespace with no effect.

It's not because it's a list of `CustomClass` and it'd work fine with strings?
I have interface set up for my customclass and can use this in VBA too. I tried a simple `List` of strings and that didn't work either.

So I **think** I might have to write a custom list-wrapping class in order to get VBA to be able to use a list, but was hoping someone could shed some light on why it's not visible and what the easiest thing to do might be.

Comment: You can use `ArrayList` in vba.

Comment: @SeM Thanks for the info, I was able to create an ArrayList and add all the same pointers as the List during class construction. I can keep my List for internal class iterations and use the ArrayList for VBA.

Comment: @jamheadart I've shared some sample code in answers, you can check it out.

Comment: Have a look at [List<T> implementation for VB6/VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32618/listt-implementation-for-vb6-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sharing with you some code example that I've used to pass collection of some object to vba:

Interface:

```
[DispId(17)]
int GetCustomerDetails(long custId, out ArrayList customerDetails);
```

Implementation:

```
public int GetCustomerDetails(long custId, out ArrayList details)
{
    // . . . getting data from provider or something

    details = provider.GetDetails(custId);

    // other stuff    

    // return code.
}
```

After successfully registration your object, you can get that data from vba this way:

```
Dim oDetails As Object
Dim obj

Private Sub SomeCommand_Click()
    Dim ret As Integer

    Set obj = CreateObject("YourObject") 'The requirement was to create object without referencing actual library

    ret = obj.GetCustomerDetails(custId.Text, oDetails)

    Dim str As String
    str = oDetails(0).YourPropertyName
    '. . .
End Sub
```

The properties should work similar way (I've not tested this part actually, let me know if something is not working):

C#:

```
public ArrayList MyListOfCustoms { get; set; }
```

VBA:

```
Dim obj

Private Sub SomeCommand_Click()

    Set obj = CreateObject("YourObject")

    Dim str As String
    str = obj.MyListOfCustoms(0).YourPropertyName

    '. . .
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access both SortedList and ArrayList via system.collections

```
Set sortedList = CreateObject( "System.Collections.Sortedlist" )
Set arrayList = CreateObject( "System.Collections.Arraylist" )
```

They have to be used with late binding or adding reference but there is no intellisense.

E.g. with ArrayList

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromguid "{BED7F4EA-1A96-11D2-8F08-00A0C9A6186D}", 2, 4
```

There is also `.AddFromFile`  method.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm going to accept SeM's answer, I'm also answering my own question with how I did it, based on the comment originally provided:

To my interface, I added the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList Attributes { get; }
```

To my class also:

```
public ArrayList Attributes { get; private set; }
```

`ArrayList`s do not take a type, since they're heterogenous.

And with minimal code I was able to pass all of my `List` to the arraylist during 
 my class construction like so:

```
Atts = new List<MyCustomClass>();
Atts.Add(a)
    ...
Atts.Add(z);

Attributes = new ArrayList(Atts); // This was the only new line I had to write.
```

This is not ideal for all scenarios where the lists will grow and shrink after initialising but for me it's perfect.

If I want to add and remove stuff from both lists I'd have to build a couple of methods.